# Create a spill function to add and subtract specific columns of data for a dynmically growing set of rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have numeric data in columns B, C and D with headings in row 1. I have the following sum in column E2 which adds all the columns together:

`=BYROW(B2#:D2#,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))`

I'd like to now add a similar function in to F2 that will calculate the following pseudo code with each row for the dynamically growing columns:

`If(B2=0,0,SUM((B2-C2-D2)/B2))`

Is there a way to adjust the first BYROW function to work with the pseudo code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `SUM()` part of the second formula (removing the need for a `BYROW`) and you can use array formula references natively:

```
=IF(B2#=0, 0, (B2#-C2#-D2#)/B2#)
```

Comment: Alternatively: `=IFERROR((B2#-C2#-D2#)/B2#,)` or `=IF(B2#,(B2#-C2#-D2#)/B2#,0)`

Answer (score 2):

### `BYROW` Subtraction

You can write your initial formula like this:

```
=B2#+C2#+D2#
```

On the other hand, if you'd have 20 or more columns, you'd most certainly want to stick with `BYROW`.

Keeping that in mind, here's an idea, as per requirement:

```
=BYROW(B2#:D2#,LAMBDA(x,TAKE(x,,1)-SUM(DROP(x,,1))))
```

following the logic

```
x-y-z=x-(y+z)
```